# ASP.Net breadcrumb style URL Routing using webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, webforms

I am working on a ASP.Net website using web-form & C#.

I have used URL Routing to convert my basic url to SEO Freindly URL for example

Basic URL

```
en/article.aspx?PageID=13&Language=en-US&parID=5&Issue=17&cid=1&aid=173&wid=17
```

After Using URL Routing

```
en/article/en-US/13/13/17/1/173/this-is-the-title-of-the-article
```

My Routing Code in global.asax

```
   routes.MapPageRoute("ArticleGeneral", "en/article/{Language}/{PageID}/{ParID}/{Issue}/{cid}/{aid}/{ArticleTitle}", "~/en/Article.aspx", false,
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Language", "en-US"},
                    { "PageID", "0" },
                    { "ParID", "0"},
                    { "Issue", "0"},
                    { "cid", "0"},
                    { "aid", "0"},
                    { "ArticleTitle", "event-not-found" }},
                new RouteValueDictionary {   
                    {"Language", "[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}"},
                    { "PageID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "ParID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "Issue", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "cid", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "aid", "[0-9]{1,8}" }
                });
```

I need to further work on this Routing to make it more like

en/article/CategoryName/WriterName/TitleOfArticle

I am not sure how i can replace ID with actual name using this routing pattern

I want to structure my pages similar to www.asp.net

```
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing
```

How can i structure my URL this way as they look clean. I am confused about this url as they are not passing any PageID's as part of URL are they using hidden fields or how they resolve these url.

My website is multilingual & I pass query-string like  PageID & LanguageID for general page & for Articles  i pass several query string as showing this example above.

I would appreciate answers regarding this with reference asp.net web-forms not MVC.

Pointer to a complete example would be great mostly example i have seen pass ID as part of Friend Url's.